# Retrieve Javascripts variables in Rails using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I got some trouble, I have no idea how to use Ajax in order to retrieve a javascript variable.

Here is the code, I think you will understand what I mean

```
%form{:name => "widget"}
  %input{:name => "color", :onclick => "ob()", :type => "radio"} Bleu/Orange
  %input{:name => "color", :onclick => "bo()", :type => "radio"} Bleu/Orange
%script{:Language => "javascript"}
  function ob()
  {
    var ojblue = 1;
  }
  function bo()
  {
    var ojblue = 2;
  }
= link_to("Edit", "#ojblue", :class => 'btn btn-info', :'data-toggle' => "modal")
```

So I'm trying to retrieve the "ojblue" value; After many searches, I know I have to use Ajax or Jquery, and the only tip I know is to use the "remote_function" method, but I don't know how to handle that...

Thanks you very much

Comment: If you declare a variable inside a function it will be visible only within that function. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Yes I know, thanks for your comment; I would like to retrieve ths variable, and pass it to my link_to.
I know the range of a javascript method, however, I don't see any other way to process even what I'm doing now is wrong, that is why I would like some helps :s Thanks